# Tracking down Area51 negative reputation changes

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, area-51, recent-activity

Is it just me, or is the reputation tab on the recent activity page just not showing negative reputation changes? I clearly have received a number of "not a good example" votes, and my reputation is changing correctly to reflect them. However *I can't seem to find them anywhere* until I go back to the actual proposal page.

Additionally, don't these votes also deserve a column in your profile page as well (next to the on-topic and off-topic votes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed recently. Negative reputation from "not a good example" votes show up in the reputation tab on your recent activity page now.

Answer (score 2):

Check it at http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: +1 This is a good workaround for now and it at least shows question ID numbers so I can track these down. Thanks. (Doesn't solve the actual problem, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Check the reputation tab on your profile. You should see the negative votes there and the questions are links to the actual questions on the proposal.

Comment: Ok this works too. I still think the recent activity page should show the whole picture though.